# Why does IntelliJ give me osgi-related warnings for a project that doesn't use a manifest file?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, osgi

After importing an existing project into IntelliJ, on several classes I get an error about org.apache.commons.lang3 classes. The format of the error is "The package 'org.apache.commons.lang3' is not imported in the manifest" when I look at a reference for the StringUtils class from this package that is being used in the class. This error shows itself in my editor as a red squiggly line under the StringUtils class.

Although this error doesn't affect my ability to compile the project, I don't like seeing errors and would like to understand it before disabling it. My project builds off of a .gradle file, and I don't have a .MF file. The gradle file specifies a compile dependency for the aforementioned package.

Comment: It looks like you have OSGI support/facet/inspections enabled for the project. If you don't care about the OSGI in this project, [disable the inspection](https://i.imgur.com/PPkRGot.png).

Comment: Thank you. I did just that, and it worked.